# Segue executed before selecting a cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I'm having an issue with my app.

I have 3 View controllers, let's name them `Oil`, `App` and `Prop` . Those 3 View Controllers are embed in Navigation controllers. And in those View Controllers I got 3 table view.

[image: Main.storyboard]

So from Up to Bottom and Left to Right :

`Prop View Controller` -> `Prop Detail View Controller`

`Oil View Controller` -> `Oil Detail View Controller`-> `Web View Controller`

`App View Controller`-> `App Detail View Controller`

So in the middle (`Oil`) Everything works fine, I click on a cell, and the `Oil Detail View Controller` is displayed, with the information I passed through my Segue.

OilViewController.m :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *sectionTitle = [aromaSectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *sectionAroma = [tableData objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    aromaNom = [sectionAroma objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Detail" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Detail"]) {
        OilDetailViewController *test = segue.destinationViewController;
        test.aromaName = aromaNom;
        test.botaniqueName.text = botaniqueName;
    }
}
```

And I'm also performing Segue between `Oil Detail View Controller` and `Web View Controller` like this :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"webView"]) {
        NSLog(@"Segue is catched");
        WebViewViewController *webView = segue.destinationViewController;
        webView.aromaUrl = _aromaName;
    }
}
```

I click on the orange button and it displays the webview.

But now if I do the SAME thing in `Prop` or `App` it doesn't work properly.

For example in `Prop Detail VC` I got a Label that displays the Property selected, but it displays me the View Controller with the label containing the old selected property before displaying me the right property selected in the label. So I have 2 `Prop Detail View` displayed AND embed in my Navigation Controller.

**I made a video of the simulator** : http://videobam.com/VwgLx

The code in `PropViewController.m` :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *sectionTitle = [aromaPropSectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *sectionProp = [propData objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    propName = [sectionProp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"prop name = %@", propName);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PropDetail" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"PropDetail"]) {
        PropDetailViewController *propView = segue.destinationViewController;
        propView.propStr = propName;
        NSLog(@"PREPARE FOR SEGUE PROP VIEW CONTROLLER");
    }
}
```

---

And in `PropDetailViewController.m` :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.propLabel.text = _propStr;
    NSLog(@"VIEW DID LOAD PROP DETAIL");
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Finally the logs :

[image: Logs]

Thanks in advance for your help, I'm stuck with this, and nobody in my team knows iOs .. So i'm alone with this !

Comment: Oh man ! Your storyboard is a web :) Can you please make simple arrangement (Side by side). I can barely see actual flow.

Comment: Forget the web on the left, it's juste link between the 3 buttons and the corresponding views .. Not that important, the important links are visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally managed to find a proper solution .. I still don't know why it works on `Oil` and causes problems on other views but still; here is the solution :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *sectionTitle = [aromaPropSectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *sectionProp = [propData objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    propName = [sectionProp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"prop name = %@", propName);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PropDetail" sender:self];
}
```

Delete the method above. And do everything you do in this method in the prepareForSegue method instead :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"PropDetail"]) {
        PropDetailViewController *propView = segue.destinationViewController;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.propTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSString *sectionTitle = [aromaPropSectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSArray *sectionApp = [propData objectForKey:sectionTitle];
        NSString *name = [sectionApp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        propView.propStr = name;
    }
}
```

Now it works fine ! But it's not logic that it works in a place, and doesn't in an other ..